# Woocommerce custom Thank You Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So my site uses the PayU India Payment gateway plugin which already has a redirect page option. So I can just choose a page from a drop down and that page is displayed after success/ failure. (I'm using the checkout/ cart page to display success/ failure messages, for now)

My website uses a custom page to display products. As it's a WPML site I have separate shop pages for each language (three languages).

1. How do I display order details and woocommerce messages on any page I create using Pages - Add new?
2. If I translate this custom page, will it be displayed when purchases are made from other languages and not default to english?

Woocommerce 3.6.4